# I can't get sfMondongoPlugin to generate embeddeds fields

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony1, odm

I'm working with the sfMondongoPlugin v1.0 https://github.com/mondongo/sfMondongoPlugin

I can not get the embeds code to generate correctly.  It generates embedded classes that inherit from the EmbeddedDocument class.  (sounds correct)

But it doesn't seem to have any reference to the embedded Class in the Parent Class.

Has anyone else had this problem?

[yml]

```
Author:
  fields:
    name: string
  embeddeds:
    phonenumber: { class: Phonenumber, type: many }

Phonenumber:
  fields:
    number: string
```